# Highcharts treemap is not displayed properly in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, highcharts

Highcharts In jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ukcqna1d/

Same code In Lightning Component displayed like this (Not showing borders):

[image]

When drilled down to another level, it is displayed like this (Not showing different colors for different blocks):

[image]

I am using highcharts version 5.0.7 and same version for treemap.

What is the problem here?

helper function

```
drawTreeMap : function(component) { 

    var points = component.get("v.userTasksData"); 
    var containers = document.getElementsByClassName("treemapContainer");       
    var series = this.getTreemapSeries(component, points);

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({      
        chart:{
            renderTo: containers[containers.length-1] 
        }, 
        series: series,
        title: {
            text: 'Userwise Activities'
        }
    });
}
```

Series

```
getTreemapSeries : function(component, data) {//data is fetched from server side. It's structure is as shown in jsfiddle above.

    var series = [{
            type: 'treemap',
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            animationLimit: 1000,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            levelIsConstant: false,
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                borderWidth: 3
            }],
            data: data
        }];
    return series;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you are using?

Comment: @ShaileshPatil Please check the edits.

Comment: Hi @nilesh_ramteke Are you sure that it's the same code in your lightning component as well? (Even before drill down, the colours are different[fiddle and in the screenshot]) Also, in the lightning component, could you please try using `jQuery version 2.2.4`?

Comment: Also, can you please add the format of the `data` in the question?

Comment: @SE_User I am not using jquery in lightning component. You can see the data in the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ukcqna1d/

Comment: Oh! But the colours shown are different in your screenshot! So, it's not even considering the values? @PawelFus Could you please provide any insights on this?

Comment: @SE_User Sorry for the goof up. Colors are randomly selected for this chart. That's why they are  different in screenshots and fiddle.

Comment: @nilesh_ramteke Colors wouldn't be randomly selected if you've used the same data as in the jsfiddle link.